# Twice data in RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

How can i fix twice data error.

After scrolling inside the `RecyclerView`, I am having a issue which is twice data.

Here is my Activity:

```
apiInterface = ApiClient.getApiClient().create(ApiInterface.class);

    Call<List<Contacts>> call = apiInterface.chat(getUserLogin,friendId);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Contacts>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Contacts>> call, Response<List<Contacts>> response) {
            contacts = response.body();
            CustomAdapterOfChat adapter = new CustomAdapterOfChat(contacts, ChatActivity.this);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            size = String.valueOf(contacts.size());
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<Contacts>> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error\n"+t.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

My customAdapter ViewHolder

```
public class CustomAdapterOfChat extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapterOfChat.MyViewHolder> {

    private List<Contacts> contacts;
    private Context context;
    String getUserLogin;

    public CustomAdapterOfChat(List<Contacts> contacts, Context context) {
        this.contacts = contacts;
        this.context = context;


    }

    @Override
    public CustomAdapterOfChat.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.items_of_chat, parent, false);
        return new CustomAdapterOfChat.MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(CustomAdapterOfChat.MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        //Fetching id from shared preferences
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
        sharedPreferences =context.getSharedPreferences(Constant.SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        getUserLogin = sharedPreferences.getString(Constant.ID_SHARED_PREF, "");

        Log.d("USER_ID",getUserLogin);
        Log.d("FRIEND_ID",contacts.get(position).getFriendId());


        holder.time.setText(contacts.get(position).getDateAndTime());
        if(getUserLogin.equals(contacts.get(position).getFriendId())) {
            holder.msg_of_me.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            holder.msg_of_them.setText(contacts.get(position).getMessage());

            holder.img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, UserProfileActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("id",contacts.get(position).getFriendId());
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                }
            });


            Glide.with(context)
                    .load(Constant.BASE_URL+"y_chat/sign_up/"+contacts.get(position).getFriendName()+"/profile.png")
                    .error(R.drawable.error)
                    .into(holder.img);
        }else{
            holder.img.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            holder.msg_of_them.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            holder.msg_of_me.setText(contacts.get(position).getMessage());

        }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return contacts.size();
}

public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    TextView msg_of_me,msg_of_them,time;
    ImageView img;
    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        msg_of_me = itemView.findViewById(R.id.message_text1);
        msg_of_them = itemView.findViewById(R.id.message_text);
        img = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_of_them);
        time = itemView.findViewById(R.id.message_time);
    }
}

}
```

Comment: What error you are facing? can you elaborate?

Comment: @Parth When i scroll inside recyclerView data is keep changing with sometimes twice data are shown together.

Comment: I suggest you to put your whole adapter class so that we can have better understanding.

Comment: @Parth Please check it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting data from `SharedPreferences` which is time consuming task however you can edit your code this way and check the output.

```
public class CustomAdapterOfChat extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

private List<Contacts> contacts;
private Context context;
String getUserLogin;

public CustomAdapterOfChat(List<Contacts> contacts, Context context) {
    this.contacts = contacts;
    this.context = context;

    //get user Id here.
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    sharedPreferences =context.getSharedPreferences(Constant.SHARED_PREF_NAME, 
    Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
     getUserLogin = sharedPreferences.getString(Constant.ID_SHARED_PREF, "");


}

@Override
public CustomAdapterOfChat.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.items_of_chat, parent, false);
    return new CustomAdapterOfChat.MyViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(CustomAdapterOfChat.MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    Log.d("USER_ID",getUserLogin);
    Log.d("FRIEND_ID",contacts.get(position).getFriendId());


    holder.time.setText(contacts.get(position).getDateAndTime());
    if(getUserLogin.equals(contacts.get(position).getFriendId())) {
        holder.msg_of_me.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        holder.msg_of_them.setText(contacts.get(position).getMessage());

        holder.img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, UserProfileActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("id",contacts.get(position).getFriendId());
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });


        Glide.with(context)
                .load(Constant.BASE_URL+"y_chat/sign_up/"+contacts.get(position).getFriendName()+"/profile.png")
                .error(R.drawable.error)
                .into(holder.img);
    }else{
        holder.img.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        holder.msg_of_them.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        holder.msg_of_me.setText(contacts.get(position).getMessage());

    }



}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return contacts.size();
}

public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    TextView msg_of_me,msg_of_them,time;
    ImageView img;
    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        msg_of_me = itemView.findViewById(R.id.message_text1);
        msg_of_them = itemView.findViewById(R.id.message_text);
        img = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_of_them);
        time = itemView.findViewById(R.id.message_time);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not working. If i show you the layout and design it will be better how to contact with you

Comment: I send you message